# How to add 30 seconds to the next duplicate primary key in MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following example of data:

```
2013-09-01 00:00, 12,13
2013-09-01 00:00, 15,16
2013-09-01 00:01, 17,20
2013-09-01 00:01, 30,45
```

that's an example of it, as you can see the first 2 lines and the next 2 lines have the same datetime, I can easily convert it and add the seconds (which will be 00 for all of them). However, each other duplicate is actually 30 seconds ahead but the data does not show it. Is there any MySQL function that whenever it finds a duplicate, it adds 30 seconds to it and inserts it?

Comment: Are those columns or something? See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: what........ by your title and the data example - is your primary key a date field??

Comment: @Strawberry They are files in a csv file, I insert them to the database with PHP, but i need to also add 30 seconds to the next duplicate.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Yes it is.

Comment: @AbdallahQaraeen change that straight away, never use a date for a primary key for this reason.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Will do.

Comment: @AbdallahQaraeen good good - haha just add a auto_increment int(8) field and then you won't need to do anything to dupe pk's because.. there won't be haha :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Alright. But i still dont know how i can add 30 seconds to every other entry?

Comment: @AbdallahQaraeen I see you have `php` as a tag - `strtotime` might be what you're looking for in this case: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I have thought of that, but how can I add it only to the second duplicate? I have like 80000 lines of text.

Comment: @AbdallahQaraeen well there what dupe are you looking for? If the PK is added, then dupe dates don't matter unless for some reason, you need unique dates?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs The dates are not actually identical, there is 30 seconds between them but it does not show in the file. so it should be like this:


    `2013-09-01 00:00:00, 12,13
    2013-09-01 00:00:30, 15,16
    2013-09-01 00:01:00, 17,20
    2013-09-01 00:01:30, 30,45`

Comment: @AbdallahQaraeen that's probably because of your insert script regarding the `H:i:s` section - do you use `date('d-m-Y H:i:s)'` to import?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Yes i do, but it will always add "00" for the seconds. I need it to add 30 each time it finds a duplicate